# Windows - what is an .rbf file?

Tags: windows-10

my windows folder is over 80gb.

I tried check through all the folders and I have a few hundred thousand of these .rbf files all in the Start Menu Folder.

I use a tool to try to calculate the size of all these files and they take up the majority of the 80gb.

```
4c6c07a.rbf
3b9d08a.rbf
```

What are they all? Do I need them, can I delete any of them?

Thanks

Comment: Those files are used to rollback to the previous version of Windows.  They will automatically be deleted after 14 days (by default). You can remove them by running the Cleanup Tool as an Administrator and select the option to delete previous version. Have you removed the previous version of Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for the comment. I just sorted by date they go back almost 12 months. I havent removed anything manually. The laptop is less than 2 years old, and I thought came with the same version.

Comment: Unless you blocked the update, Windows 10 was upgrade to the version, at least once in that timeframe.

Comment: AFAICT, there is no "start menu folder" in the default windows-10 "windows folder". They are located in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` perhaps the OP can clarify the location of these files

Comment: Important because "folder/filename" mimicking are SOP for poorly designed malware or spyware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RBF file is Archive of files created during software installation
by the Windows Installer. It contains files that can be restored if the
installation does not successfully complete.

If the installation is successful, the rollback file should be
automatically deleted upon reboot.

I have no idea why these files have not been deleted on your computer.
I suggest to do a cold shutdown and reboot twice, to check if these
files disappear.

Otherwise, you could delete them yourself. Start with one `.rbf` file,
move it to a backup folder, and wait a day or two. If nothing bad happens,
you could delete all of them.